# Class system architecture in C ++

Tags: c++, class

For my latest project I have a class

```
class Parent {
    public:
        // class constructor
        Parent();
        
        // member function
        double fun(double x)
};
```

and another class

```
class Child {
    private:
        int type;
    public:
        // class constructor
        Child(int itype);
};
```

I know that I can inherit the functions from `Parent` by specifying `class Child : public Parent` so that instances of my class `child` can call `fun`. However, I want that the function `fun` perform different computations depending on `type`. For instance, if an instance of my `Child` class was initialized by `Child nChild(1);` the call `nChild.fun(5)` should return the square root of `5`, while initializing the class by `Child nChild(2);` the call `nChild.fun(5)` should return the logarithm of `5` and so on.

How could I design a system of classes with dependencies such that the function in the parent class depends on the value of the child class? Does this even make sense or is or is generally advised against such a architecture? Note that I am not a C++ expert.

Comment: Read up on the keyword `virtual` and how it applies to functions.

Comment: the member variable type can take on any value when the program is running but the class hierarchy has to be fully defined at compile time. So you cannot have the class hierarchy somehow be dependent on the value of a variable.

Comment: Perhaps you want to create a factory-function like ‘Parent * createObject(int itype);’ that allocates and returns an object of a different subclass depending on the value of ‘itype’?  Then you could make ‘double fun(double x)’ virtual and implement it differently in each different subclass you define.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't have separate functions in the parent, such as square root and logarithm, rather than dispatching via a code?

Comment: Maybe not use `int`, but instead a class that has the operation that needs to be performed on the value?  You are tying the `type` to a number, but why do that when you can just pass a class that has all the information, including the function to perform on the value.  I don't even see the need for `Parent` if you did things that way, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: there are many different child classes which need to access functions in the parent class. The idea is to add more and more functions to the parent class. Example: one child class could be 'realNumber', another could be 'Matrix'. For both objects there is a notion of square root. However the computation slightly differs depending on whether the square root of a real number or the square root of a matrix should be computed.

Comment: my first idea was to "unify" the child class that's why I thought about a type variable that tells my parent what to do.

Comment: thanks for all the comments. I am going to look up the virtual keyword. This may be a possible solution already

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a `protected: int myType;` in the parent class and use that in the derived class to switch on. However the better design is to make a diffrent derived class for each type that would override the `fun()` method.

```
class Parent
{
public:

    Parent();

    virtual double fun(double x) = 0;
};

class ChildLog : public Parent
{
public:
    ChildLog();
    double fun(double x)
    {
        // return log(x)
    }
};

class ChildSqrt : public Parent
{
public:
    ChildSqrt();
    double fun(double x)
    {
        // return sqrt(x)
    }
};
```